# Docker for GUI-based environments on windows

Tags: docker, opencv, xserver

i am trying to make a dockerfile to  opencv social distance detection project as a requirement to school project

the problem that i had is to make docker run on GUI-based environment

somehow i managed to make it work on **linux** by adding the fellow line to the run command

> -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:ro

the full command

> sudo docker run -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v
> /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:ro  social-distance-detection -y
> https://youtu.be/hTUyzF4v9KA

but it did not work on windows

which command should i add to **docker run** so it can run on windows ?
and by any chance is there a way to make it even work without adding any extra line ?

there is the Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
FROM python:3.8

LABEL maintainer="muhammed akyuzlu ***@gmail.com"

ADD Social-distance-detection.py / 
ADD coco.names / 
ADD yolov4.cfg /    
ADD yolov4.weights /  




RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
    python3-pyqt5 \
    build-essential \
    cmake \
    git \
    wget \
    unzip \
    yasm \
    pkg-config \
    libswscale-dev \
    libtbb2 \
    libtbb-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libtiff-dev \
    libavformat-dev \
    libpq-dev \
    xserver-xephyr\
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN apt-get update -y \ 
    && apt-get install python3-pip -y \
    && pip install pafy \
    && pip install numpy  \
    && pip install youtube-dl \
    && pip install numpy \
    && pip install opencv-python 


ENTRYPOINT ["python","./Social-distance-detection.py"]
```

it is my first time with Docker so you could find some nonsense lines  :)

Comment: I don't think this really works (though can't say authoritatively): since you're running a Linux container, you need a Linux-compatible (X Window System) display system, and even then the setup is rather finicky.  The half-dozen [SO Docker Windows tkinter questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdocker%5D+tkinter+windows) by and large don't have answers at all.  Can you run this on a native Windows Python, using a virtual environment for package isolation?

Comment: How can i run it  on a native Windows Python ?
Do i need to change something inside the Dockerfile ?

Comment: Delete the Dockerfile entirely, install Python, and use that to run your interactive GUI application (without Docker).

Comment: And on the subject of nonsensical lines - using two FROM lines one after another is pointless - the first one is essentially ignored, also your actual base image already has Python installed, so installing the system version is a very bad idea - you don't know which one you're actually using. Finally, you should never have two `RUN` instructions one after another, but put everything into one.

Comment: @DavidMaze first thank you second  i would love to not install docker and play with it but as i mentioned it's for a school project they asked to be in the docker container

now i need to explain how to install X Window Server inside my documantion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, clean up your Dockerfile. I would suggest:

```
FROM python:3.8

LABEL maintainer="muhammed akyuzlu ***@gmail.com"

COPY Social-distance-detection.py / 
COPY coco.names / 
COPY yolov4.cfg /    
COPY yolov4.weights /  

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install \
    build-essential \
    cmake \
    git \
    wget \
    unzip \
    yasm \
    pkg-config \
    libswscale-dev \
    libtbb2 \
    libtbb-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libtiff-dev \
    libavformat-dev \
    libpq-dev \
    xserver-xephyr && \
    apt-get -y clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir pafy \
    numpy  \
    youtube-dl \
    PyQt5 \
    opencv-python 

ENTRYPOINT [ "python" , "./Social-distance-detection.py" ]
```

I'm not going to repeat my comment to your question, but as for other changes - you should use `COPY`, rather than `ADD`, unless you need ADD-specific features. You should only run `apt-get install` once, then clean up all temporary files and caches. You should run `pip` with `--no-cache-dir` switch to avoid creating unnecessary caches in the first place.

Now for your actual question. As @David Maze suggested you need to install X Window Server, then configure it to accept all connections and finally run:

```
docker run -e DISPLAY=192.168.1.68:0.0 social-distance-detection -y https://youtu.be/hTUyzF4v9KA
```

replacing `192.168.1.68` with your host's IP address.

The process is described in detail in [this article](https://cuneyt.aliustaoglu.biz/en/running-gui-applications-in-docker-on-windows-linux-mac-hosts/).

Comment: thanks a lot for you guysa 
mini question in my ubuntu 20.04 i can run the opencv on gpu can i make it run on gpu inside the container ?
it wasn't essay to make it run on ubuntu you need to install cuda and cmake vb .

Comment: I have a cv2.so if that would help

Comment: It’s possible if your host system is Linux: https://www.datamachines.io/blog/toward-a-containerized-nvidia-cuda-tensorflow-and-opencv or a beta version of Windows and if you’re running Docker daemon via WSL 2 rather than Hyper-V: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl-user-guide/index.html#installing-wip. It’s not my area of expertise, though, so if you have issues getting it to run, I won’t be able to help.